# Asp.Net Mvc highlighting current page link technique?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to highlight active link in the menu. My menu is in the master page by the way. I'm looking for the best way to implement this? Any ideas?

Comment: Hw do you store menu items? You can associate them with controller and action and highlight basing on these values.

Comment: I'm storing them in a masterpage as static.

Comment: Already covered here? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471362/how-to-visually-indicate-current-page-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: This article helped me: [Highlighting current page in MVC 3](http://bhavinsurela.com/highlighting-current-page-in-mvc-3-slick-tric/)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to write an HTML helper. You could use  `RouteData.Values["action"]` to get the currently executing action and compare to the menu name and if they match apply a CSS class that will highlight it.

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
    string action, 
    string text
)
{
    var menu = new TagBuilder("div");
    var currentAction = (string)htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
    if (string.Equals(
            currentAction, 
            action,
            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    )
    {
        menu.AddCssClass("highlight");
    }
    menu.SetInnerText(text);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(menu.ToString());
}
```

And then use this helper to render the menu items:

```
<%: Html.MenuItem("about", "About us") %>
<%: Html.MenuItem("contact", "Contact us") %>
...
```

Comment: Hi, Darin.  Where does one put HTML Helpers?  A new folder and then use "imports" to include it?  How can I use this?  Thanks.

Comment: There's no convention nor specific place to put the custom HTML helpers. Personally I place the extension methods in a Helpers folder.

Answer (score 8):

I am always using this solution
Html Part

```
<ul>
   @Html.ListItemAction("Home Page","Index","Home")
   @Html.ListItemAction("Manage","Index","Home")
</ul>
```

Helper Part

```
 public static class ActiveLinkHelper
    { 
      public static MvcHtmlString ListItemAction(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, string actionName, string controllerName)
      {
        var currentControllerName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var currentActionName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("<li{0}", (currentControllerName.Equals(controllerName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                                            currentActionName.Equals(actionName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                                ? " class=\"active\">" : ">"));
        var url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
        sb.AppendFormat("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", url.Action(actionName, controllerName), name);
        sb.Append("</li>");
        return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this solution:

First - add attribute data-menuPageId to your menu links

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li data-menuPageId="home">
            @(Html.Link<HomeController>(x => x.Index(), "Home"))
   </li>
   <li data-menuPageId="products">
            @(Html.Link<ProductsController>(x => x.Index(), "Products"))
   </li>
</li>
```

Next - add hidden field for current page Id to Layout.cshtml

```
<input type="hidden" id="currentPageId" value="@(ViewBag.Page ?? "home")" />
```

Add ViewBag.Page initializtion at your pages like Home or Products

```
@{
    ViewBag.Page = "products";
}
```

And last thing you should reference this javascipt from yor Layout.cshtml

```
$(function() {
    var pageIdAttr = "data-menuPageId";
    var currentPage = $("#currentPageId").attr("value");

    var menu = $(".menu");

    $("a[" + pageIdAttr + "]").removeClass("selected");
    $("a[" + pageIdAttr + "=\"" + currentPage + "\"]", menu).addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In layout try like following:

```
@{
    string url = Request.RawUrl;
}
@switch (url)
{
    case "/home/":                
         @Html.ActionLink("Home", "../home/", null, new { @style = "background:#00bff3;" })
         @Html.ActionLink("Members", "../home/MembersList/")
    break;
    case "/home/MembersList/":
         @Html.ActionLink("Home", "../home/")
         @Html.ActionLink("Members", "../home/MembersList/", null, new { @style = "background:#00bff3;" })
    break;
    default:
            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "../home/")
            @Html.ActionLink("Members", "../home/MembersList/")
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution:

1) Connect jQuery to @RenderBody ()

2) On Layout

```
...                        
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="navItemPortfolio" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
</li>
```

...

3) Write something similar on your page (View)

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#navItemPortfolio").addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do this with pure CSS. It involves class selectors and faffing around with the body tag. I would go with the helper method every day of the week.