# ASP.NET MVC: How do you get the current URL of the page in the view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is probably easy, although I cant seem to find the solution.
In my view I have links in a partial view which acts as a menu.
I need to apply an active class to the anchors if they are the page currently being viewed.

What I therefore need is a quick and simple method of checking the href of the link against the url of the page?

Any takers? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")
```

will give you the action that was used to render this view. As far as good practices are concerned I would recommend you [writing an HTML helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643613/asp-net-mvc-highlighting-current-page-link-technique/3644139#3644139) that will do the job instead of polluting your views with C#.