# ASP.NET MVC: Highlighting current link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to highlight current link in menu, But structure of HTML is look like below:

```
<li class="active">
    <a href='@Url.Action("MainPage", "Ticket")'>
        <i class="fa  fa-fw fa-home"></i>
        HomePage
    </a>
</li>
```

I know there are many different solutions to do that ([+](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/25/asp-net-mvc-highlight-current-link.aspx), [+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643613/asp-net-mvc-highlighting-current-page-link-technique)):

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(
            this HtmlHelper helper,
            string text, string action, string controller)
        {
            var routeData = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
            var currentController = routeData["controller"];
            var currentAction = routeData["action"];

            if (String.Equals(action, currentAction as string,
                      StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                &&
               String.Equals(controller, currentController as string,
                       StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return helper.ActionLink(
                    text, action, controller, null,
                    new { @class = "active" }
                    );
            }
            return helper.ActionLink(text, action, controller);
        }
```

But my HTML structure is a little bit different.
How can I do that?
Any idea?

Comment: What was your question, have you tried those different solutions?

Comment: Whats so different? Just modify the code to return the html you want.

Comment: @StephenMuecke `a` tag also has `i` inside itself

Comment: As I said, just return what you want rather that `return helper.ActionLink(text, action, controller);`. Use `TagBuilder` to generate the `<i>`, `<a>` and `<li>` tags and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I changed the code this way and it works: (Thanks to @Stephen Muecke)

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(
            this HtmlHelper helper,
            string content, string action, string controller)
        {
            var routeData = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
            var currentController = routeData["controller"];
            var currentAction = routeData["action"];

            var builder = new TagBuilder("li")
            {
                InnerHtml = content
            };
            if (String.Equals(action, currentAction as string,
                      StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                &&
               String.Equals(controller, currentController as string,
                       StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                builder.AddCssClass("active");
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
        }
```